# Kotlin: how do i check if the app has already been opened once?

Tags: kotlin, sharedpreferences

I'm building an app in Flutter and need to run a snippet of code in Kotlin to check whether or not the app is on it's first run.

I found out that this is the code in Java, but how do I go about doing it in Kotlin?

```kotlin
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences prefs = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Perhaps set content view here

        prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.mycompany.myAppName", MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true)) {
            // Do first run stuff here then set 'firstrun' as false
            // using the following line to edit/commit prefs
            prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you copy-paste Java code into a Kotlin source file in Android Studio, it converts it for you.

Comment: all that code is doing is trying to get a stored value called ``firstrun``, and defaulting to ``true`` if it doesn't exist (i.e. if it hasn't been set yet, presumably because it's the first run!). And then after doing whatever on the first run, they're setting that value for next time. It's exactly the same in Kotlin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple actually:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : Activity() {

    private lateinit var sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(packageName, MODE_PRIVATE)
    }
    
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (sharedPrefs.getBoolean("firstRun", true)){
            sharedPrefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit()
        }
    }

}
```